# Against the "restrictions" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

So, we have a [restrictions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/restrictions) tag. I believe it is much too vague and general.

Now, true, it has 95 associated questions, but they should either just lose the tag or get more specific tags, existing or new, such as [privileges](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/privileges) (exists) or [access-restrictions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access-restrictions).

What say you?

Comment: Access restrictions seems meta taggy too. Ideally would be more specific tags about ACLs and such